# Minimising Database Queries in Wordpress when using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a page which lists staff members for a large company and trying to minimise the number of times I'm forced to query the database as it gets quite complex and slow.

- `'person'` is a custom post type (there are about 300 people)
- `'date_accredited'` is a date field added via Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Only accredited staff will have a `'date_accredited'`.

I need to list every `'person'` BUT, with ALL accredited staff listed first (so about 20 accredited staff come at the top).

At the moment, I am doing a call to WP_Query like:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'people', 
    'no_found_rows' => true, 
    'meta_key' => 'date_accredited'
);
$people = new WP_Query($args);
```

After that I'm doing:

```
while($people->have_posts()): $people->the_post();      
    $my_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_accredited', true);
    if (!empty($my_post_meta)) {
        array_push($accredited, $post);
    } else {
        array_push($notAccredited, $post);
    }
endwhile;
```

Leaving us with two arrays of 'person' objects. My thinking here was that I would be able to do something like the following to get the list I want:

```
foreach($accredited as $person):
    personTile($person);
endforeach;

foreach($notAccredited as $person):
    personTile($person);
endforeach;
```

I'm trying to avoid re-querying the database.

The `personTile();` function was supposed to output various info and HTML (`the_post_thumbnail()` and various Advanced Custom Fields fields), but what I'm realising now is that none of this is included in the post objects I get from `WP_Query()`, so I'm forced to use things like:

- `get_the_post_thumbnail($person->ID)`
- `get_permalink($person->ID)`
- `get_field('date_accredited', $person->ID)`

All of these cost another DB Query (each!), and worse still since they are in a loop each one happens around 300 times.

Is there any way to get the permalink, thumbnail and ACF fields to be included in the original DB Query? Would I need to resort to a custom MySQL Query???

Any other suggestions welcome!

Comment: Here's what fields I actually get in my `$person` objects from Wordpress:

ID, post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type, post_mime_type, comment_count, filter